# How to display RGB and depth image from Kinect on odroid-XU4?

Tags: kinect, ros, openni, odroid

I installed Lubuntu 14.04 on my odroid-XU4. I installed ROS Indigo along with the openni_camera and openni_launch. They seemed to work properly because I was able to subscribe to some of its published topics. Now, I want to display the RGB and Depth images from kinect using ROS packages. How should I proceed further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type: "roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch" from command line. You can use Rviz to visualize RGB and Depth images. Open rviz from command line, typing: "rviz" then click the add button and go to the tab "By Topic". You should find the topic in which the images are published.